# Package conflict between eso-pic and wallpaper

Tags: graphics, incompatibility, eso-pic

The following code gives me a conflicting options message. Does anyone know if there is a way to fix it?

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
%\input{this-preamble}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[grid, gridcolor=red!20, subgridcolor=green!20]{eso-pic}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{textblock}{4}(5,-0.5){\Huge{General Overview of some very important stuff}}\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No conflict on my system (only some overfull box warnings). What error message are you getting?

Comment: Oops sorry. Edited to include the bit that had stopped working. i.e. `\usepackage{wallpaper}` The error is `!LaTeX Error: Option clash for package eso-pic ... l.## \usepackage[left=0.5in,right=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After getting the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package eso-pic.
```

and typing "h" (for help) in an output console, you get an explanation of the problem and a possible solution:

```
The package eso-pic has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [grid, gridcolor=red!20, subgridcolor=green!20]
Adding the global options:
  ,grid, gridcolor=red!20, subgridcolor=green!20
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

Doing as recommended, you prevent the clash:

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,grid, gridcolor=red!20, subgridcolor=green!20]{article}
%\input{this-preamble}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{textblock}{4}(5,-0.5){\Huge{General Overview of some very important stuff}}\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that `wallpaper` internally loads `eso-pic` *without* options, so loading `eso-pic` (after `wallpaper`) with options produces the clash; another solution is to load `eso-pic` with options *before* `wallpaper`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
%\input{this-preamble}
\usepackage[grid, gridcolor=red!20, subgridcolor=green!20]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{textblock}{4}(5,-0.5){\Huge{General Overview of some very important stuff}}\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```